# ArrayList.add not working with AsyncTask

Tags: android, arrays, json, arraylist, android-asynctask

I'm using fragment view to show `ListView` in my Android Application. It is working perfectly when I manually enter `ArrayList`. But now I want to add JSON array to the `ArryList` in `AsyncTask` class and add that `ArrayList` to Adapter.

So I got JSON array and put It `ArrayList`. This process doing in the `AsyncTask` class.

I execute that `AsyncTask` class in `onCreateView()` method in Fragment. Then I set `ArrayList` to Adapter. But problem is there..

After execute `AsyncTask` class get my JSON array perfectly and add to the `ArrayList`. But when I try to add my `ArrayList` to Adapter. Then my `ArryaList` empty.

This my fragment class with `AsyncTask` Part

```
public class FragmentCategory extends Fragment {

private ListView lvCategory;
private CategoryAdapter categotyAdapter;
private List<Category> mCategoryLst;

View view;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category , container, false);
    lvCategory = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_category);
    mCategoryLst = new ArrayList<>();
    /*mCategoryLst.add(new Category(1, "hghjj" ,null));
    mCategoryLst.add(new Category(2,"Abcd", null));
    mCategoryLst.add(new Category(3,"Aeec", null));*/
    new FetchDataTask().execute();
    if(mCategoryLst!=null && mCategoryLst.size()>0) {
        categotyAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(getContext(), mCategoryLst);
    }

    lvCategory.setAdapter(categotyAdapter);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //new FetchDataTask().execute();

}
public class FetchDataTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,Void>
{
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    private String mUrlCategory;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog.setMessage("Downloading your data...");
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface arg0) {
                FetchDataTask.this.cancel(true);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        Uri bUri = Uri.parse(getString(R.string.url_category));
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(bUri.toString());
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();
            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            if(inputStream==null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                buffer.append(line + "\n");
            }

            if(buffer.length() == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }
            mUrlCategory = buffer.toString();                

        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } /*catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } */finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
            if (reader != null) {
                try {
                    reader.close();
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    Log.e("MainActivity", "Error closing stream", e);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        try {
            if (progressDialog.isShowing())
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(mUrlCategory);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                int id = Integer.parseInt(jObject.getString("id"));
                String name = jObject.getString("categoryName");
                String imageUrl = jObject.getString("iconPath");

                mCategoryLst.add(new Category(id, name ,null));
            }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());
} // catch (Exception e)
    }
}

}
```

This my Category class
This one using for create `ArrayList`

```
public class Category {

private  int categoryId;
private String categoryName;
private String imgUrl;

public Category()
{

}

public Category(int id,String name, String img)
{
    this.categoryId=id;
    this.categoryName=name;
    this.imgUrl=img;
}

//Gettert

public int getCategoryId() {
    return categoryId;
}

public String getCategoryName() {
    return categoryName;
}


public String getImgUrl() {
    return imgUrl;
}

//Settert


public void setCategoryId(int categoryId) {
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
}

public void setCategoryName(String categoryName) {
    this.categoryName = categoryName;
}

public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl) {
    this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
}
}
```

This my Adapter class

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private List<Category> mCategoryList;

//Constructor


public CategoryAdapter(Context mContext, List<Category> mCategoryList) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mCategoryList = mCategoryList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mCategoryList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mCategoryList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.item_category, null);
    TextView tvCategoryName = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.category_name);
    ImageView ivCategoryImg = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img_category);
    //Set Value
    tvCategoryName.setText(mCategoryList.get(position).getCategoryName());
    //ivCategoryImg.setImageResource();
    //Set ID
    v.setTag(mCategoryList.get(position).getCategoryId());

    return v;
}
}
```

Comment: add this line `categotyAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(getContext(), mCategoryLst); lvCategory.setAdapter(categotyAdapter);` in your `onPostExecute` method it will work

Comment: Even better Use `categotyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after adding data in your `mCategoryLst` inside `onPostExecute` method of your `FetchDataTask` asynctask

Comment: @Nilesh Thank you.. It's working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved
I change my `onPostExecute()` method like this...

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    try {
        if (progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(mUrlCategory);

        Log.v("Response", jsonObject.toString());

        JSONArray categoryArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("itemcategory");
        for (int i = 0; i < categoryArray.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jCategory = (JSONObject) categoryArray.get(i);

            int id = Integer.parseInt(jCategory.getString("id"));
            String name = jCategory.getString("categoryName");
            String imageUrl = jCategory.getString("iconPath");

            mCategoryLst.add(new Category(id, name, null));
        }

        if (mCategoryLst != null && mCategoryLst.size() > 0) {
            categotyAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(getContext(), mCategoryLst);
        }

        lvCategory.setAdapter(categotyAdapter);
        categotyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());
    } // catch (Exception e)
}
```

When I put this part

```
if (mCategoryLst != null && mCategoryLst.size() > 0) {
    categotyAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(getContext(), mCategoryLst);
}

lvCategory.setAdapter(categotyAdapter);
```

in `OnCreateView()` application not working. So I put It in `onPostExecute()`. Then It work perfectly. Thanks All

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter when you have the data:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

     JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

     int id = Integer.parseInt(jObject.getString("id"));
     String name = jObject.getString("categoryName");
     String imageUrl = jObject.getString("iconPath");

     mCategoryLst.add(new Category(id, name, null));
 }
 categotyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
categotyAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(getActivity(), mCategoryLst); 
lvCategory.setAdapter(categotyAdapter);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

as per your code, what i see, make changes like below code, for Fragment OnCreateView() and OnPostExecuation of AysncTask class.

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category , container, false);
    lvCategory = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listview_category);
    mCategoryLst = new ArrayList<>();
    /*mCategoryLst.add(new Category(1, "hghjj" ,null));
    mCategoryLst.add(new Category(2,"Abcd", null));
    mCategoryLst.add(new Category(3,"Aeec", null));*/
    new FetchDataTask().execute();

 categotyAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(getContext(), mCategoryLst);
    lvCategory.setAdapter(categotyAdapter);
    return view;
}
```

And in OpPostExecution

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        try {
            if (progressDialog.isShowing())
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(mUrlCategory);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject jObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                int id = Integer.parseInt(jObject.getString("id"));
                String name = jObject.getString("categoryName");
                String imageUrl = jObject.getString("iconPath");

                mCategoryLst.add(new Category(id, name ,null));
            }
    categotyAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSONException", "Error: " + e.toString());
} // catch (Exception e)
    }
```

Comment: This is not working for me. but thank you. Your answer was help to me solved this problem